# Routing issue... Resource not found - MVC3

Tags: vb.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, routes

Having issues getting myself started on MVC3

Trying to define a simple route here in `Global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute( _
  "MeGet", _
  "me", _
  New With {.controller = "MeController", .action = "Show"}, _
  New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint("GET")}
)

routes.MapRoute( _
  "MePut", _
  "me", _
  New With {.controller = "MeController", .action = "Update"}, _
  New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint("PUT")}
)
```

And My controller is as follows.

```
Public Class MeController
  Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

  '
  ' GET: /me
  Public Function Show() As ActionResult
    Dim stuff = {"Hello", "World"}

    Return Json(stuff, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  End Function

  '
  ' PUT: /me
  Public Function Update() As ActionResult

    Return View()
  End Function

End Class
```

And all I get is...

> The resource cannot be found.

no stack trace.

***Following Suggestions***

Changed Controller to `_me` and tried the Route Debugger

Now it says there is **NO MATCH!** but below it says it matches the current request...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class _me
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```

must become:

```
Public Class MeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```

in ASP.NET MVC convention dictates that controller class names are suffixed with `Controller`. I don't know why did you put an _ before your controller name, it is against conventions but if you ever decide to keep it you will have to reflect this in your route definitions as well.

Also in your routes replace:

```
.controller = "MeController"
```

with:

```
.controller = "Me"
```

so that your route definition looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
  "MeGet", _
  "me", _
  New With {.controller = "Me", .action = "Show"}, _
  New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint("GET")}
)

routes.MapRoute( _
  "MePut", _
  "me", _
  New With {.controller = "Me", .action = "Update"}, _
  New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint("PUT")}
)
```

Comment: Changed and error persists... I assume `_me` is because `Me` is a keyword in VB, I just clicked create controller and named it me.

Comment: changed code in question to reflect suggestion that still errors out.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, in your route use `.controller = "Me"` and not `.controller = "MeController"`. You seem to have edited your initial question.

Comment: the code in the question now reflects the current state, which still errors out...

Comment: @ jondavidjohn, in your routes.MapRoute replace `.controller = "MeController"` by `.controller = "Me"`!!! Remove the controller suffix from the routes and keep it in the controller name class. I have updated my answer to illustrate more clearly.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, of course, it's first thing you read when you learn ASP.NET MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `_` in the controller name: `.controller = "_me"`

Comment: Try the [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).

Comment: So it says the defined route matches the current request, but it also says there's no match :/ http://cl.ly/1y3u0O152o2k14281U2u

Answer (score 0):

Add `Public` to your action methods.

You'll also need to pass `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.

Comment: Updated controller code to current after all suggested edits, with same error. Thanks, btw.